# Is there reference of Rukmini killing demons?

Tags: scripture, krishna, demon, rukmini

I heard that Rukmini, the wife of Krishna, killed a demon named Dindhirasura. Is there any mention in texts? If yes, can you provide the name of the book and the chapter which mentions this incident?

Comment: This is from local legend of Pandharpur, Maharashtra